Is it always possible to write an symmetric incidence matrix of a projective plane?
I've been doing a personal project on finite projective planes (inspired by the Spot It game) and have developed a conjecture: each finite projective plane can be represented by a symmetric incidence matrix. I have been able to generate a symmetric matrix for each finite projective plane up to order 6; but as of yet I can't see any pattern in these matrices. I'm wondering if the conjecture is true, and if so, is there a formula for generating these symmetric matrices? Also if true, how many unique symmetric matrices exist for a given finite projective plane?
(Attaching the symmetric matrices for order 1 through 6 below: a red square represents an entry of 1, and a blue square an entry of 0.)







I have answered your question, but I do not understand your images. What do you mean in particular by a projective plane of order 1 or 6? Such planes do not exist, yet you give matrices for them. Also the matrix for a plane of order $n$ should be $(n^2 +n+1)\times(n^2+n+1)$, so your matrices are much too small.

Ah I think I see, you have two small matrices that do not correspond to any projective plane, and then you have planes of order 2 through 5 represented, I believe?

No this is not true. The existence of a symmetric point-line incidence matrix requires a projective plane to be self-dual; this means that if we exchange the role of points and lines in the incidence structure, we obtain a new projective plane that is isomorphic to the one we started with.
However, there exist projective planes that are not self-dual. In fact most are not. There are exactly four non-isomorphic projective planes of order 9, two of which are self-dual and the other two are duals of each other; these are the smallest non-self-dual examples.
